# Netbeans Maven annotations not supported in source 1.3, use source 5

Tags: maven, netbeans, compiler-construction, maven-plugin

When building my projects using Maven from Netbeans 6.7, I get these error messages:

```
Error   annotations are not supported in -source 1.3   (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
```

I've already seen on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513479/maven-install-annotations-are-not-supported-in-source-1-3) that I need to add a maven-compiler-plugin configuration to my POM.xml, but I don't want to do this to every project. Can I set this in one central location that will affect all my maven projects? In settings.xml somehow?

I've already configured Netbeans to use Maven 3.0.3 and my JAVA_HOME is pointing to JDK 1.5.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531650/default-maven-compiler-setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it is quiet simple using Netbeans to configure this in each project :

- right click on your project,
- select «properties»,
- select «sources» in the project properties window,
- choose the «source/binary/format» to 1.3
- click OK will update your pom correctly.

A better approach will be to use  ([inheritance in poms](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance)) .

Configure the plugin in a parent pom.xml :

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
      <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
      <name>parent-pom</name>
      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.3</source>
                        <target>1.3</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

Then after, your modules can inherit this behaviour this way :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>mavenproject1</name>
```